# Configure eXist - LDAP security manager

Tags: ldap, exist-db

I am trying to configure eXist to LDAP to authenticate users and I have checked out the documentation at [eXist LDAP Security](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/ldap-security.xml). Turns out the default configuration only supports three settings:
`security.ldap.connection.url` (The connection URL of the LDAP server), `security.ldap.dn.user`(The user list DN), and `security.ldap.dn.group` (The group list DN).

It doesn't work for my case because the LDAP server does not enable anonymous queries, which means I have to provide the user name/password in order to establish the connection.

Any suggestion on how I could achieve this other than enable anonymous queries on the LDAP server?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can implement your own context factory and feed it to exist with the **security.ldap.contextFactory** parameter.

The context factory is the java class used to initialize a connection to the directory. You can implement a context factory that initializes the connection with the ad-hoc credentials.

The idea is to implement a class like this:

```java
public class MyCustomContextFactory implements InitialContextFactory {

  public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable env) {

    // Fetch the application DN and password somehow (config file...)
    String applicationDN = ...;
    String password = ...;

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, applicationDN);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    return new InitialDirContext(env);

  }
}
```

You generate a jar file, add it in the classpath of your server, and specify the configuration parameter:

```
security.ldap.contextFactory = your.java.package.name.MyCustomContextFactory
```